# Combinations and Permutations of coin tossing.

Tags: probability, combinations

Toss a fair coin 20 times. Find out how many outcomes have 7 H's and 13 T's.

Comment: Please share your efforts in solving the problem

Comment: The way my book describes it has the solution as 20C7/20^2. My question for that would be why divide it by the total number of possible outcomes? Wouldn't that be irrelevant data for this question? @ncmathsadist answer seems the most logical too me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have twenty tosses, choose 7 and make 'em heads and the rest tails. There are ${20\choose 7}$ ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks! My book has you dividing the solution by the total number of outcomes which seems irrelevant too me. This is what I thought the answer was in the first place.